# c# Database timestamp

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to know when the database was timestamped from c# code.. Is this possible and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the database was timestamped"? You question is currently too vague to answer.

Comment: Get the latest time of when a new record was inserted in the database. Then check if that time happened before this hour. If yes run an sql procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you *may* want a column in your table which is automatically updated by the database itself on update (e.g. with a trigger). Personally I prefer to let the database perform this task rather than the client, as it means you can get it right in one place and be certain that nothing else can modify the data (even with SQL entered manually) without the timestamp being updated.

Of course, that's assuming you're talking about a row-level timestamp recording the last change. The question isn't clear about that.

Comment: Especially given that you can then manage transactional support much more easily.

Comment: I don't want to add a column in the database.. what I really want is to get the time when the latest row was inserted and then check if that time happened before this hour. If yes run an sql procedure.

Comment: @Mark: Well you'll have to store the data *somewhere*. You could potentially create a separate table with one row per "normal" table that you want this for, and update a record in that table based on a trigger on the original table.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as below and store in the database

```
private String GetTimestamp(DateTime value) {
    return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
}
```

This will give you a string like 201105211035131468

Comment: Isn't there another way instead of storing it in the database like an sql query which will return the timestamp. I will be using this to run another query if a change was made within an hour